# ConstraintLayout and changing contraints programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to change the constraints programmatically as follows:

```
final ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();  
set.clone(this);  
if(text == null) {
    view.setVisibility(GONE);
    set.clear(div.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP);
    set.connect(div.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, otherView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
 }
 set.applyTo(this);
```

But the rule is not applied. The `div` goes to the top of the layout like there is no top constraint.
What am I doing wrong?

**Update**
If I change the following:

```
set.clone(this);  
...
set.apply(this);
```

to:

```
View root = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, this);  
ConstraintLayout layout = root.findViewById(R.id.constraint_layout);  
....
set.clone(layout); 
....
set.apply(layout);
```

The layout is correct! But I don't understand why.
`this` is a `ConstraintLayout` since I am extending a `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: Can you tell what `this` means in your code? *(I.e. `set.clone(this)`)*

Comment: @JeelVankhede: This code is inside a class that `extends ConstraintLayout`. Hence `this` is refers to this derived class

Comment: @JeelVankhede: by the way, if in the Android Studio editor, I make the `view` as `gone` and then change the constraint of `div` to have as top the bottom of `otherView` it shows ok in the editor preview. When I run that code programmatically the layout is messed up as mentioned in the post